# Cannot start Springboot as init.d service on port 80

Tags: linux, sudo, symlink, sysvinit, port

I've been following the official guide to [setting up Springboot as an init.d service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service) on an Amazon Linux ec2 instance. Before I got to this setup, I was running into the problem where [I could not start the server on port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635109/the-tomcat-connector-configured-to-listen-on-port-80-failed-to-start) when I executed the jar manually. The solution to this was to execute the jar as root, and I moved on.

Now, I have finished making the necessary changes to my project's gradle.build and created the symlink to my executable jar, and I can do

```
sudo service myapp start
```

and I get some indication that the process is running just fine. However, the process exits after a few seconds. If I check the logs in /var/log/myapp.log, it contains ***the same error*** I was getting before when trying to start the server manually as a non-root user

```
2018-04-13 13:01:31.793  INFO 23583 --- [           main] 
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-04-13 13:01:31.816  INFO 23583 --- [           main] 
ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run 
your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-13 13:01:31.817 ERROR 23583 --- [           main] 
o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start. The 
port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's 
listening on port 80, or configure this application to listen on another 
port.

2018-04-13 13:01:31.818  INFO 23583 --- [           main] 
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@4c3e4790: startup date [Fri Apr 13 13:01:26 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-13 13:01:31.820  INFO 23583 --- [           main] 
o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

So when I start the service as root, it doesn't have the same permissions as though I just manually executed the jar.

Tl;dr:
how do I start Springboot to listen to port 80 (requires sudo) as an init.d service?

Note this is my first time dealing with Linux in anything more than a testing capacity, so I half-expect the solution to be really obvious due to my lack of experience.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the following facts:

- Ports below 1024 can be opened only by root.
- Running a Spring Boot web application with root privileges is a bad idea. Because, if the application is compromised the attacker gain root privileges.

One solution is to run an httpd Apache server as a reverse proxy and redirect request on port 80 to a port higer than 1024 on localhost. For this you can use the [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) Apache directive.

Here is an article about this technique: [Using Apache as a Reverse Proxy for Spring Boot Embedded Tomcat](https://medium.com/@codebyamir/using-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-f704da73e7c8)

The main Apache configuration looks like this:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't really looking for a secure answer, as this was just an experience project.

The solution I found for myself was to set the owner of the symlink to root.

```
sudo chown root myapp
```